# Highlight multiple keywords from a given string

Tags: php, keyword, highlight

I need to highlight each word separately from a string, even if the string is only one word.

`$keyword = 'should be bolded';`

`$string = 'This shouldbebolded';`

Expected result:

"This **shouldbebolded**."
This is the Google like highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using 
[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), 
[`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and 
[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
<?php
# Keywords
$keywords_str = 'tv nice';

# String
$string = 'My tv is nice';

# Operation result(to not modify $string)
$result = $string;

# Split $keywords by spaces into array of single keywords
$keywords = explode(' ', $keywords_str);

# Loop keywords array
foreach($keywords as $keyword)
{
    # Replace every keyword occurence to make it bold
    $result = str_replace($keyword, "<b>$keyword</b>", $result);
}               

echo $result;

?>
```

And the result would be:

> My **tv** is **nice**

Answer (score 2):

A simple function will suffice your requirement. You can break your words into an array to search for all of them separately.

Simply use `explode()` function to break your words into array and pass it to the function below.

```
function highlightWords($string, $words)
 {
    foreach ( $words as $word )
    {
        $string = str_ireplace($word, '<span class="highlight">'.$word.'</span>', $string);
    }
    return $string;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use the function since I need it in multiple places. Regards.