# How to highlight strings in a file to download?

Tags: php, highlight

I have a text file "output.txt" which is an output of a shell command. I want to highlight certain words taken as $_GET['word'] in that file and then allow to download using href.

I have seen multiple questions but none of them seems to be working in this case.

1. [Highlight multiple keywords from a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343064/highlight-multiple-keywords-from-a-given-string)
2. [highlight the word in the string, if it contains the keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483844/highlight-the-word-in-the-string-if-it-contains-the-keyword)

Code:

```
$cmd = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/clustalw2 -infile=input.txt -tree -type=protein -case=upper &");
$file = 'output.txt';
$content = explode("\n",file_get_contents("output.txt"));
$keyword = $_GET['word'];
$content = str_replace($keyword,'<span style="color:red">'.$keyword.'</span>',$content);
$file = file_put_contents($file, $content);
echo "<a href='http://some.thing.com/folder/output.txt'>Download Result file</a>";
```

It is not giving any error neither highlighting the text.

Comment: What happens with this code? You are using the shell or a browser? HTML won't highlight in a text editor, nor the shell.

Comment: `file_get_contents(output.txt)` should cause an error.

Comment: @user3783243 I am using a browser. This script is running on a server.

Comment: @user3783243 sorry I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the trouble is with opening the initial file. The following did work for me.

I created /home/input.txt:

```
this is a test
that may
or may not work.
```

Then ran:

```php
$cmd = shell_exec(" cp /home/input.txt output.txt");
$file = 'output.txt';
$content = explode("\n",file_get_contents("output.txt"));
$keyword = "may";
$content = str_replace($keyword,'<span style="color:red">'.$keyword.'</span>',$content);
$file = file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $content));
echo "<a href='http://some.thing.com/folder/output.txt'>Download Result file</a>";
```

And the output.txt is now:

```html
this is a test
that <span style="color:red">may</span>
or <span style="color:red">may</span> not work.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is still not highlighting the words :(

Comment: In my case, I used the keyword "may" and it produces the color tag. Where is  the highlighting not showing up?

Comment: in the browser (chrome).

Comment: I understand, but which part? Is it the "Download Result File" link or the content of the file that you don't see on chrome? The content has a txt extension so it would not render. If I change it to output.html, I get this https://i.imgur.com/DgTCzdF.png

Comment: yes, the content part. oh I see! Let me try this html extension.